# Custom enumitem list reset conditional variable

Tags: environments, conditionals, counters, enumitem

I've defined a new list like this:

```
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{mdframed}

\newcommand{\questionlabel}{Question }
\newcommand{\restorequestionlabel}{\renewcommand{\questionlabel}{Question }}
\newcommand{\setquestionlabel}[1]{\renewcommand{\questionlabel}{#1 }}
\newlist{questions}{enumerate}{4}
\setlist[questions]{
    align=left,
    ref=\questionlabel\arabic*,
    label=\textbf{\questionlabel\arabic*.},
    wide
}
\newif\ifquestionsincludelabel
\newcommand{\includelabel}{\questionsincludelabeltrue}
\newcommand{\excludelabel}{\questionsincludelabelfalse}
\newcommand{\question}[2][]{
    \needspace{10\baselineskip}
    \ifquestionsincludelabel \item #1 \else \item[] #1 \fi
    \mbox{}\begin{mdframed}#2\end{mdframed}
}
```

It uses conditionals to determine whether to print the label. Is there a way to reset this conditional, i.e. execute `\includelabel`, every time a new list is started with `\begin{questions}`? It'd be easy to do if `questions` were defined using `\newenvironment`, but it uses `enumitem`'s `newlist` instead.

P.S. when the conditional branch with `\item[]` is executed, the counter is not incremented. I'd like to automatically do it, but putting `\addtocounter{???}{1}` doesn't work as I don't know the name of the counter. Is there a way to target the current list or the innermost one (`questionsi`, `questionsii`, etc.)?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Can you please expand the code snippet that you have posted to a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228). A MWE should compile and be as *small as possible* to demonstrate your problem. it's much easier to help you if we have full working code to start from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer to your question is that you just need to add

```
 before=\includelabel
```

to the definition of `questions`. In fact, I would just set `\ifquestionsincludelabel` to be true directly using

```
\setlist[questions]{
    align=left,
    ref=\questionlabel\arabic*,
    label=\textbf{\questionlabel\arabic*.},
    wide,
    before=\questionsincludelabeltrue
}
```

This said, I wonder whether you need to use `\ifquestionsincludelabel` at all and whether a better syntax is given by defining a starred version of `\question` so that `\question` includes the label and `\question*` does not. The easiest way to define `\question` this way is using `\NewDocumentCommand` from the [xparse](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/xparse) package:

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\question}{ s O{} m }{
    \needspace{10\baselineskip}
    \IfBooleanTF{#1}{\item #2}{\item[]#2}
    \mbox{}\begin{mdframed}#3\end{mdframed}
}
```

Although, possibly you want to switch the starred and unstarred behaviour.

The `s O{} m` says that this command has three arguments:

- An optional '*' as `#1`. As above, you can test to see if a `*` has been used with

  ```
   \IfBooleanTF{#1}{...true code}{...false code}
  ```
- An optional label, `#2`, that defaults to `{}`. (This is your previous `#1`.)
- A mandatory `#3`, which is put inside the `mdfamed` environment

For more details see the [xparse manual](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/xparse). It's very readable.

Here is a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228)

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{mdframed}

\newcommand{\questionlabel}{Question }
\newcommand{\restorequestionlabel}{\renewcommand{\questionlabel}{Question }}
\newcommand{\setquestionlabel}[1]{\renewcommand{\questionlabel}{#1 }}
\newlist{questions}{enumerate}{4}
\setlist[questions]{
    align=left,
    ref=\questionlabel\arabic*,
    label=\textbf{\questionlabel\arabic*.},
    wide,
    before=\questionsincludelabeltrue
}
\newif\ifquestionsincludelabel
\newcommand{\includelabel}{\questionsincludelabeltrue}
\newcommand{\excludelabel}{\questionsincludelabelfalse}
\NewDocumentCommand{\question}{ s O{} m }{
    \needspace{10\baselineskip}
    \IfBooleanTF{#1}{\item #2}{\item[]#2}
    \mbox{}\begin{mdframed}#3\end{mdframed}
}

\begin{document}

  \begin{questions}
    \question {Some text}
    \question[2]{More text}
    \question*{Even more text}
    \question*[4]{Last bit of text }
  \end{questions}
\end{document}
```

and here is the output:

[image]

Btw, it is not clear to me that you need to wrap this inside an `enumerate` environment, as it is not doing that much except making it clear that all of the questions belong "together". You could do equally well with something like:

```
\newcounter{question}
\NewDocumentCommand{\question}{ s O{} m }{%
        \needspace{10\baselineskip}%
        \refstepcounter{question}%
        \IfBooleanTF{#1}%
          {\item \textbf{\questionlabel\space\thequestion} #2}%
          {\item[]#2}%
        \mbox{}\begin{mdframed}#3\end{mdframed}
    }
```